# How to print all dates from Weather API XML

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, api, object

Sorry for any lq thing, am new to c#.

Am trying to display all dates from XML WEB API...

I already printed for only 1 date, I want for 5 days?

I need to display in Console application all data for 5 days just like I post for one date.

What should I use, can anyone help me please?

replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.replacing text, because stack doesn't let me post, says mostly code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientWeather = new RestClient("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx");//?key=c37f984779f14beb9bf01943201104&q=Pristina&format=json&num_of_days=5");
                                                                                                        //client.Timeout = -1;
        var requestWeather = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        requestWeather.AddParameter("key", "c37f984779f14beb9bf01943201104", ParameterType.QueryString);
        requestWeather.AddParameter("q", "London", ParameterType.QueryString);
        requestWeather.AddParameter("format", "xml", ParameterType.QueryString);
        requestWeather.AddParameter("num_of_days", "5", ParameterType.QueryString);
        IRestResponse responseWeather = clientWeather.Execute(requestWeather);

        var xmlDeserializer = new XmlDeserializer();
        var place = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Request>(responseWeather);
        var temp = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Current_condition>(responseWeather);
        var dit = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Weather>(responseWeather);
        var data1 = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<Data>(responseWeather);


        Console.WriteLine("Place: " + place.Query);
        Console.WriteLine("Temp momentale: " + temp.FeelsLikeC);

        Console.WriteLine("Temp for 5 days.");

        Console.Write("Date         " + "TempMin    " );
        Console.WriteLine("TempMax");

        Console.WriteLine(dit.Date + "      " + dit.MintempC + "    " + dit.MaxtempC);


        Console.ReadLine();













        Console.ReadLine();
    }





    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "request")]
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "query")]
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "current_condition")]
    public class Current_condition
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "observation_time")]
        public string Observation_time { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "temp_C")]
        public string Temp_C { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "temp_F")]
        public string Temp_F { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherCode")]
        public string WeatherCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherIconUrl")]
        public string WeatherIconUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherDesc")]
        public string WeatherDesc { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "windspeedMiles")]
        public string WindspeedMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "windspeedKmph")]
        public string WindspeedKmph { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "winddirDegree")]
        public string WinddirDegree { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "winddir16Point")]
        public string Winddir16Point { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "precipMM")]
        public string PrecipMM { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "precipInches")]
        public string PrecipInches { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "humidity")]
        public string Humidity { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "visibility")]
        public string Visibility { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "visibilityMiles")]
        public string VisibilityMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pressure")]
        public string Pressure { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pressureInches")]
        public string PressureInches { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "cloudcover")]
        public string Cloudcover { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FeelsLikeC")]
        public string FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FeelsLikeF")]
        public string FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uvIndex")]
        public string UvIndex { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "astronomy")]
    public class Astronomy
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sunrise")]
        public string Sunrise { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sunset")]
        public string Sunset { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "moonrise")]
        public string Moonrise { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "moonset")]
        public string Moonset { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "moon_phase")]
        public string Moon_phase { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "moon_illumination")]
        public string Moon_illumination { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "hourly")]
    public class Hourly
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "tempC")]
        public string TempC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "tempF")]
        public string TempF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "windspeedMiles")]
        public string WindspeedMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "windspeedKmph")]
        public string WindspeedKmph { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "winddirDegree")]
        public string WinddirDegree { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "winddir16Point")]
        public string Winddir16Point { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherCode")]
        public string WeatherCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherIconUrl")]
        public string WeatherIconUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weatherDesc")]
        public string WeatherDesc { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "precipMM")]
        public string PrecipMM { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "precipInches")]
        public string PrecipInches { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "humidity")]
        public string Humidity { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "visibility")]
        public string Visibility { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "visibilityMiles")]
        public string VisibilityMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pressure")]
        public string Pressure { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pressureInches")]
        public string PressureInches { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "cloudcover")]
        public string Cloudcover { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "HeatIndexC")]
        public string HeatIndexC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "HeatIndexF")]
        public string HeatIndexF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DewPointC")]
        public string DewPointC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DewPointF")]
        public string DewPointF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WindChillC")]
        public string WindChillC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WindChillF")]
        public string WindChillF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WindGustMiles")]
        public string WindGustMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WindGustKmph")]
        public string WindGustKmph { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FeelsLikeC")]
        public string FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FeelsLikeF")]
        public string FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofrain")]
        public string Chanceofrain { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofremdry")]
        public string Chanceofremdry { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofwindy")]
        public string Chanceofwindy { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofovercast")]
        public string Chanceofovercast { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofsunshine")]
        public string Chanceofsunshine { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceoffrost")]
        public string Chanceoffrost { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofhightemp")]
        public string Chanceofhightemp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceoffog")]
        public string Chanceoffog { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofsnow")]
        public string Chanceofsnow { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "chanceofthunder")]
        public string Chanceofthunder { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uvIndex")]
        public string UvIndex { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "weather")]
    public class Weather
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "astronomy")]
        public Astronomy Astronomy { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "maxtempC")]
        public string MaxtempC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "maxtempF")]
        public string MaxtempF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "mintempC")]
        public string MintempC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "mintempF")]
        public string MintempF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "avgtempC")]
        public string AvgtempC { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "avgtempF")]
        public string AvgtempF { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "totalSnow_cm")]
        public string TotalSnow_cm { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sunHour")]
        public string SunHour { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uvIndex")]
        public string UvIndex { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "hourly")]
        public List<Hourly> Hourly { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "month")]
    public class Month
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "index")]
        public string Index { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "avgMinTemp")]
        public string AvgMinTemp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "avgMinTemp_F")]
        public string AvgMinTemp_F { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "absMaxTemp")]
        public string AbsMaxTemp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "absMaxTemp_F")]
        public string AbsMaxTemp_F { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "avgDailyRainfall")]
        public string AvgDailyRainfall { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ClimateAverages")]
    public class ClimateAverages
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "month")]
        public List<Month> Month { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
    public class Data
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "request")]
        public Request Request { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "current_condition")]
        public Current_condition Current_condition { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "weather")]
        public List<Weather> Weather { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ClimateAverages")]
        public ClimateAverages ClimateAverages { get; set; }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Why the big wall of repeating text in your question?

Comment: If that is your real API key, I would advise removing it - posting real API keys publicly is a _dangerous_ thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize xml to a collection of specific objects, like this:

```
//request and response code omitted for brevity

var dit = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<List<Weather>>(responseWeather);

foreach(var date in dit)
{
     Console.WriteLine(date.Date + "      " + date.MintempC + "    " + date.MaxtempC);
}
```

output:

```
2020-04-20      9    15
2020-04-21      9    15
2020-04-22      11    16
2020-04-23      12    20
2020-04-24      11    19
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you have my respect :) .

Answer (score 0):

I modified the URL.  You were getting json and not xml. See xml linq below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=c37f984779f14beb9bf01943201104&q=Pristina&num_of_days=5";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            List<TemperatureDate> dates = doc.Descendants("weather").Select(x => new TemperatureDate()
            {
                date = (DateTime)x.Element("date"),
                avgtempF = (int)x.Element("avgtempF"),
                hourTemp = x.Elements("hourly").Select(y => new KeyValuePair<int,int>(((int)y.Element("time"))/100, (int)y.Element("tempF"))).ToList()
            }).ToList();

       }
    }
    public class TemperatureDate
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public int avgtempF { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> hourTemp { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

using serialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=c37f984779f14beb9bf01943201104&q=Pristina&num_of_days=5";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
            data data = (data)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class data
    {
        public request request  { get; set; }
        public current_condition current_condition { get; set; }
        public weather weather { get; set; }
    }
    public class request
    {
        [XmlElement("type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string query { get; set; }
    }
    public class current_condition
    {
        public TimeSpan observation_time { get; set; }
        public int temp_C { get; set; }
        public int temp_F { get; set; }
        public int weatherCode { get; set; }
        public string weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
        public string weatherDesc { get; set; }
        public int windspeedMiles { get; set; }
        public int windspeedKmph { get; set; }
        public int winddirDegree { get; set; }
        public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
        public  decimal precipMM { get; set; }
        public decimal precipInches { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public int visibilityMiles { get; set; }
        public int pressure { get; set; }
        public int pressureInches { get; set; }
        public int cloudcover { get; set; }
        public int FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
        public int FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
        public int uvIndex { get; set; }
    }

    public class weather
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public astronomy astronomy { get; set; }
        public int maxtempC { get; set; }
        public int maxtempF { get; set; }
        public int mintempC { get; set; }
        public int mintempF { get; set; }
        public int avgtempC { get; set; }
        public int avgtempF { get; set; }
        public decimal totalSnow_cm { get; set; }
        public decimal sunHour { get; set; }
        public int uvIndex { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("hourly")]
        public List<hourly> hourly { get; set; }
    }
    public class astronomy
    {
      public TimeSpan sunrise { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan sunset { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan moonrise { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan moonset { get; set; }
      public string moon_phase { get; set; }
      public int moon_illumination { get; set; }
    }
    public class hourly
    {
      public int time { get; set; }
      public int tempC { get; set; }
      public int tempF { get; set; }
      public int windspeedMiles { get; set; }
      public int windspeedKmph { get; set; }
      public int winddirDegree { get; set; }
      public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
      public int weatherCode { get; set; }
      public string weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
      public string weatherDesc { get; set; }
      public decimal precipMM { get; set; }
      public decimal precipInches { get; set; }
      public int humidity { get; set; }
      public int visibility { get; set; }
      public int visibilityMiles { get; set; }
      public int pressure { get; set; }
      public int pressureInches { get; set; }
      public int cloudcover { get; set; }
      public int HeatIndexC { get; set; }
      public int HeatIndexF { get; set; }
      public int DewPointC { get; set; }
      public int DewPointF { get; set; }
      public int WindChillC { get; set; }
      public int WindChillF { get; set; }
      public int WindGustMiles { get; set; }
      public int WindGustKmph { get; set; }
      public int FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
      public int FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
      public int chanceofrain { get; set; }
      public int chanceofremdry { get; set; }
      public int chanceofwindy { get; set; }
      public int chanceofovercast { get; set; }
      public int chanceofsunshine { get; set; }
      public int chanceoffrost { get; set; }
      public int chanceofhightemp { get; set; }
      public int chanceoffog { get; set; }
      public int chanceofsnow { get; set; }
      public int chanceofthunder { get; set; }
      public int uvIndex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is XML also i needed with XmlSerializer. - 
        requestWeather.AddParameter("format", "xml", ParameterType.QueryString);

Comment: Xml is default.  You had json in the comments.  I updated code for xml serilization